# how remove white space after and before specific character

Tags: javascript, replace

```
const text = 'hey : "bob " Hey    Hello'
text.replace(' "', '"').replace('" ', '"')

// expect result 'hey :"bob"Hey    Hello'
```

how to replace this whitespace before and after (")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to capture a substring like `ABC` and remove leading and trailing whitespace with this regex.

`test.replace(/\s*(ABC)\s*/g, $1);`

Answer (score 2):

To stay close to your initial idea,

Where `\s*\"` means any number of whitespaces before the `"` symbol and `\"\s*` means any number of whitespaces after the `"` symbol. The `g` after the regular expression is [a flag which means global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags).

```
text.replace(/\s*\"/g, '"').replace(/\"\s*/g, '"')
```